# How to post user id in edit method Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Its my header through which i am moving on edit profile

```
                    <li><a href="{{route('user.profile')}}"></li>
```

i want to send id of user which is **$user->id** how can i pas it to this to get in edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'name')->get();


    $page_data = [
                    'title' => 'Edit User Account',
                    'action' => 'edit'
                 ];

    return view('user.create');

}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific. From where you are sending the request? What's your route?

Comment: yes i have update my question @shoieb0101

Comment: `user.profile` shows the form for editing user details, right? Which route you are using to submit that form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}"></li>
```

From within the profile you post your data to:

```
route('user.edit', ['id' => $user->id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps:

inside: **routes.php**

```
Route::get('edit/{id}', [
     'as' => 'user.profile', 
     'uses' => 'YourController@edit'
]);
```

And your view, you can do this:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">Edit</a>
```

[Laravel URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route)